# I have all my templates in $templateCache, but Angular is making requests anyway

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, angular-ui-router

I'm using [gulp-angular-templatecache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache) to put all my .html files in the $templateCache when deploying my app.

The problem is that Angular (and ui-router) are ignoring this and sending requests to the server, even though my routes' names are exactly the same names that $templateCache is using to store the files.

Example of one state:

```
.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    templateUrl: '/base/view/app.html',
    controller: 'AppController as appCtrl'
});
```

And $templateCache:

```
$templateCache.put('/base/view/app.html', '<div>...</div>');
```

This won't work. It's still requesting the app.html.
However, if I remove templateUrl and use $templateProvider instead, it will work. Like this:

```
.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    templateProvider: ['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
        if ($templateCache.get('/base/view/app.html')) {
            return $templateCache.get('/base/view/app.html');
        }
    }],
    controller: 'AppController as appCtrl'
});
```

But there are tons of states and directives and I would need to manually replace them all. So I created an interceptor of http requests to check if it's requesting an .html, if it is, then check if it's cached and return it, otherwise, make the request.

However, I'm unable to stop the request and return what I want. I can only stop it but I can't put a 'fake' response on it.

What I have tried:

```
'request': function(config) {
    var url = angular.copy(config.url);
    if (url.indexOf('.html') !== -1) {
        var cachedData = $templateCache.get(url);
        if (!_.isUndefined(cachedData)) {
            var cachedPromise = $q.defer();
            config.timeout = cachedPromise.promise;
            cachedPromise.resolve();
            // config.timeout is used to stop the request but it doesn't matter the response of the promise, it's probably ignored and just used to stop the request.
        }
    }
    return config;
}
```

Is there any way to make this interceptor work? Another idea would be to alter the ui-router source code to make it check $templateCache beforing sending the request ([It looks like it does check the cache](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/1e46c8d/src/templateFactory.js#L82), but only after the first request. I want to check it even before the first request). Besides that, I'm out of ideas... Any way to make this work without changing the source code of ui-router?

Comment: I really doubt that `$templateCache.put` won't work. Where did u put this clause?

Comment: `$templateCache.put` is working. See what I said about using `$templateProvider` instead of `templateUrl`. The problem is that **ui-router** doesn't check the cache beforing sending the request.
This clause is at a `.run` function in my initialization module.

Comment: Could u try log the `config.url` in the request interceptor? AFAIK ui-router should check the cache as long as the url matches.

Comment: ui-router will check the cache, but only _after_ the first request. See [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/1e46c8d/src/templateFactory.js#L82). It calls $http.get with a cache parameter, so I think it will check **$templateCache** only after the first call (it doesn't check before that and the cache parameter on the $http is not set before that either).

Comment: According to [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L1261) the cache should be checked before every request including the first one. So I doubt that the config.url differs from the one u set manually.

Comment: I checked, and the url matches.

Comment: Then that is wired. One possible cause of this issue I can think of is that you put your template cache initialization and the route config in two separate modules with no dependency to each other. This could somehow make then do not share the same $templateCache service.

Comment: I checked again while changing the `templateUrl` name and it worked. I still need to check why, but it seems to have something to do with the `/base` before the rest of the path. For example, my `$templateCache` is storing the template at `/base/view/app.html`, and if my `templateUrl` is `/base/view/app.html` it will **not** work. But if I change the `templateUrl` to `view/app.html` it will work. Thank you for your help, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Maybe it is something to do with the base url of your application. Good luck!

Comment: There is something really weird going on. I said it worked but there is something else. Storing the template at `/base/view/app.html` and `templateUrl` pointing to `view/app.html` will work only if I put an interceptor that will add `/base/` to the url, that means that in the end the url will be `/base/view/app.html`, which makes no sense because if I remove the interceptor and make `templateUrl` point to `/base/view/app.html`, it won't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the problem.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (typeof(toState) !== 'undefined') {
        $templateCache.remove(toState.templateUrl);
    }
});
```

That is why it was working with the interceptor. The code above was disabling $templateCache, but the interceptor is executed after that. So, remember to check your handlers, interceptors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had too a similar problem, and MMhunter's comment has saved me!

> Then that is wired. One possible cause of this issue I can think of is
>   that you put your template cache initialization and the route config
>   in two separate modules with no dependency to each other. This could
>   somehow make then do not share the same $templateCache service.

gulp-angular-templatecache is using or creating (with standalone:true option) a module  for template caches. This module must be added as a dependency in root app's module.

So, if you have this cache:

```
angular
.module('templates', [])
.run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) { 
$templateCache.put('get-time/get-time.html', '<div style="background-color:darkgray;"><h1>Get Time</h1><p>The time is: {{time}} <img src="/Areas/Admin/assets/img/clock.png" width="100"></p></div>'); }]);
```

Then you must have a dependency like this:

```
angular.module("app", ["templates"])
```